# Querying timestamp column In q

Tags: kdb

I want to count the number of records inserted in a kdb+ database using a q query.

Currently, using below query:

```
count select from executionTable where ingestTimeStamp within 2019.09.07D00:00:00.000000000 2019.09.08D00:00:00.000000000
```

It works but not highly performant. Any recommendations to make it efficient is highly appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the table you are querying?
What is the current performance and what do you expect? It will be useful to know the number of records retrieved, and the system details (if you are querying from disk, how is it stored on disk, what are the disk details)

Comment: Number of records are in few hundred thousands per day. Currently, it takes about 2 secs to get the results. Don't have much other information. If you see any obvious fix in the query please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you querying on disk data? How has it been saved down (serialized, partitioned etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want count then use 'count i' inside select like below:

```
q) select count i from executionTable where ingestTimeStamp within 2019.09.07D00:00:00.000000000 2019.09.08D00:00:00.000000000
```

This will only get the count instead of fetching full data which is what your query is doing and that's one of the reasons for taking more time.

And if it is a partitioned database, then add 'date' in the filter as @Callum Biggs mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you have provided I'm assuming you're querying on-disk data, likely saved in a standard date partitioned structure. In this case, you should be specifying a date clause before you specify a time clause, this will prevent searching *all* the date directories.

```
select from executionTable where date=2019.09.07, ingestTimeStamp within 2019.09.07D00:00:00.000000000 2019.09.08D00:00:00.000000000
```

I'd suggest reading through the whitepaper on [query optimization](https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/columnar-database/), it will give some guidance in good query structure, and how to take advantage of map reduction in kdb.